# Are there any countries which currently block or plan to block Bitcoin?

Tags: legal

Are there any countries which currently block or plan to block Bitcoin? If anyone has enough reputation to edit this, maybe add "censorship" or maybe "freedom" as a tag because i can't.

Comment: I changed the tag to "legal" which is a tag that has been used quite a lot already. "Block" really refers to something else so I removed that tag.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that Charles Schumer (D-NY) and Joe Manchin (D-WV) of the U.S. senate [sought a law criminalizing it](http://www.reuters.com/article/2011/06/08/us-financial-bitcoins-idUSTRE7573T320110608) back in 2011. Guess the media moved on and the law stalled.

There are also countries like Venezuela, which criminalize exchange of a 'foreign currency', under the Foreign Exchange Crime Act. Essentially, this is so they can pretend that bolivars are worth more than they really are.

Now, is bitcoin a 'foreign currency'?

> “Foreign Currency:  Any currency, whether in coins, bank notes, bank checks and in any form, other than the bolivar, the latter being understood to be the legal tender in the Bolivarian Republic of Venezuela, as well as securities denominated in foreign currency or that can be settled in foreign currency.”

Technically, yes.

[Source](http://www.bpmaw.com/eng/c_cambios2010-eng.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no known incident of bitcoin blocking.